# node.js json-server data are cached

Tags: json, node.js

I'm using the following json-server

```
var server = jsonServer.create()
var router = jsonServer.router('./books/db.json')
server.use(jsonServer.defaults())
server.use(router)
server.listen(3000)
```

I change db.json every 5 seconds

```
setInterval(function() {
    var o = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./books/db.json', 'utf8'));
    for (var i = 0; i < o.books.length; i++) {
        // do some changes
    }
    fs.writeFile("./books/db.json", JSON.stringify(o));
}, 5000);
```

the file is changing but when doing a request, it stills has the old data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json-server` uses `lowdb` internally for [serving static files](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/blob/master/src/server/router/index.js#L28). `lowdb` won't reload your file on change as it is not watching the file for changes. The `lowdb` database is available at `router.db`, so you can use `router.db.read('./books/db.json')` to read your file again after changing it. See the [lowdb docs](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb#api) for the API.

Alternatively, read the section of the `json-server` docs pertaining to [generating random data](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#generate-random-data). This solution avoids continual disk access, but your data will be lost after the server exits. If this is not an issue, this would the the way I would go.